# How many ports count in the modern operating systems?

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming

TCP and UDP protocols have 16-bit port field. Therefore operating systems network stacks, functions and structures have 16-bit values for the port.
But is it possible situation, when operating system has more than 65535 ports?

Comment: No, but remember that something like a TCP connection uses both the source and destination IP and TCP addresses to identify the connection, so it is really a 96-bit identifier (32 IP and 16 TCP source bits plus 32 IP and 16 TCP destination bits). The address (port) numbers are in the transport protocol header, not the OS. TCP and UDP ports use the same range, but are different things. TCP port 12345 is _not_ UDP port 12345.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Yes, I understand this. Limitation is the protocol characteristic. But the question is different.
Theoretically I can imagine situations, where more than protocol-limited ports are possible and even useful.
But is it implemented anywhere?

Comment: I do not understand the problem. Ports are addresses for _some_ transport protocols, and  are not part of the OS. The transport protocols, e.g. TCP, multiplex on a single port, allowing more connections on one port than a host can handle. The port limitations are part of the transport protocol architecture.

Comment: You would need to use a different (possibly non-existent, future) protocol to get around that. You seem to assume the OS has the ports, but it does not. So far, the 16-bit address (port) has proven to be enough. There was a window when TCPv6 for IPv6 was defined, but it kept the 16-bit address, even as IPv6 addresses were expanded to 128 bits. You could, of course, create your own transport protocol with a larger address space, but IPv4 NAPT only supports ICMP, TCP, and UDP, so you would need to use it internally or with IPv6.

Comment: There is no problem, it was a student's question and not about protocol implementation.
What if "extended port number" exists only inside OS network stack for multiplex to isolated environments (containers, etc.)? Yes, I understand, that containers have own address or share the host network.
Imagine (it's just an imagination), that we have containers, that shared the host network, but "port spaces" are different (i.e. 0-65535, 65536-131072, ...). OS knows about port spaces, but apps inside containers and outside node use "normal" port numbers. OS multiplexes requests by the source address.

Comment: Of course, if we'll have protocol with an extended port range, we'll need more ports. But this situation is not very interesting. Interesting variant is a possibility to have port range more, than used by protocol. According to your answers, I realized that a such idea is not implemented anywhere. Thank you.

Comment: But, "what if"..?

Comment: What do you mean, "what if?" There are many different transport protocols. Some use port numbers, some use something else, and some use nothing for addressing. You can certainly create your own transport protocol that uses port numbers which use a field size other than 16 bits. The number of ports in your protocol will be up to you and your design, but both TCP and UDP use a 16-bit field, and `2^16=65536`. Also, your PC will still be unable to exhaust the number of ports today when they are actively used, much less more ports than that.

Comment: "what if?", - a hypothetical situation, where this would be useful (for existing protocols or another protocols with 16-bit length field). But, I understood: this is useless in practice, and even regardless of the protocol's length field, this is not necessary.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But is it possible situation, when operating system has more than 65535 ports?

Not with any protocol that uses a 16-bit field for the port number. It's not up to the operating system since it's part of the protocol and you cannot change that without changing *all* existing hosts.

As Ron Maupin has pointed out, that isn't normally a practical limitation since an application can use a single port to communicate with an arbitrary number of hosts. A socket is defined by the tuple *source IP, destination IP, L4 protocol, source port, destination port*. As long as that tuple is unique, the socket is unambiguously defined.

The number of L4 ports may become a bottleneck with *network address (port) translation* (NAPT) but business-grade NAT routers usually support using a pool of public IP addresses instead of just a single one.

> What if "extended port number" exists only inside OS network stack for multiplex to isolated environments?

If you define your own transport-layer protocols you can make that field 128 bit if you wish. Practically, there's no need to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understood: no, because it is useless. All practical problems can be solved without increasing the maximum number of ports.

Comment: Essentially, the OS can't do anything else than follow the protocol that's fixed with 2^16-1 ports. And more isn't really required.

Comment: Some addition to the answer: look at the "SO_PORT_SCALABILITY" options in the Windows. "Proxy server environments have scalability issues because of limited local port availability. One way to work around this is to add more IP addresses to the machine. However, by default wildcard ports used with the bind function are limited to the size of the dynamic port range on the local machine no matter the number of IP addresses on the local machine. Working around this requires the application to maintain its own port pool either with port reservation or by using heuristics."

Comment: @A.N. *SO_PORT_SCALABILITY* enables parallel re-use of local ports to in turn enable more than 64K *socket connections*. It does not in any form increase the local port count.

Comment: Yes, obviously, but this is a situation when it is desirable that the number of ports in the system be more than the protocol allows in a 16-bit field.

Comment: @A.N. Sorry, but I fail to see any use case where you'd need *more than 65,000 socket connections to a single host* which is the actual hard limit of that 16-bit field.

Comment: Not for single host to single host. But what if several thousand hosts use this host as a proxy to download something (and use, for example, up to 10 connections)? I think without this option, WinSock has one common port space, independent of the addresses.